# Leverage browser caching for the static files

Tags: go, browser-cache, static-files

I am not sure, how in Golang we can leverage browser caching for only static files like `CSS`, `js` and not `HTML` template file.

With `.htaccess` in Apache, it used to be easy, but I don't see any such thing in `golang`

I want to know, any hack or method available where I can cache static files like `css`, `js`

**without using cloudflare** - My app does not work with cloudflare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser caching is controlled by headers  sent by the server. This way it doesn’t depend on particular installed software.

You need to send headers `Etag` and `Cache-Control`.  Like this

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    e := "SomeKey describing content - eg checksum"
    w.Header().Set("Etag", e)
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=2592000") // 30 days

    if match := r.Header.Get("If-None-Match"); match != "" {
        if strings.Contains(match, e) {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotModified)
            return
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Useful links:

- More details https://www.sanarias.com/blog/115LearningHTTPcachinginGo
- Middleware example https://github.com/dc0d/cache-control by [Kaveh Shahbazian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54467/kaveh-shahbazian)
- Intro to HTTP caching and headers http://dev.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Comment: It also cache HTML pages.

Comment: I caches things you say: you may send such headers for static files and another (like `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0` and no `Etag`) for dynamic content to prohibit caching.

Comment: I am using kataras/iris and it has StaticWeb function without callback https://github.com/kataras/iris/blob/5a59eb7d46cbcb412139dfdc5bf9da277baaf93e/_examples/file-server/basic/main.go

Comment: It can not distinguish with static files and HTML files.

Comment: I've developed this package for adding ETag and Cache-Control headers based on content of the file. This part is fully implemented. (https://github.com/dc0d/cache-control)

Comment: @user3767643 I don't recommend using kataras/iris at all.

Comment: for what reason ?

Comment: @KavehShahbazian Please explain why not Kataras/IRIS ?

Comment: A very strange product which will never gather healthy community because of his author. Gophers can't accept his way of development. I don't want to be subjective to anybody so recommend to get objective image better to consult Google.  about the author and Iris. So you are in risk to obtain once  an unsupported product.

Comment: @user3767643 About that, Eugene Lisitsky explained it.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are using golang does not mean that you cannot use a reverse proxy like ngnix or apache to deal with browser caching and other crucial things you want out of the box and not have to deal with them directly in your api

Comment: That would be completely unnecessary though, and adds an external dependency with its own installation, configuration, and resource requirements. If all you need is to set cache headers, a reverse proxy is way way overkill.

Comment: That's true and sensible. Conversely, many companies have cloud infrastructure that already uses reverse proxies - so they are a valid option in many situations.